# Make uibutton pulsate.

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I am trying to make a uibutton that has an image in it pulsate slowly by changing the alpha level back and forth once the view loads...

currently I am doing this but it does nothing....

```
-(void)loopdyloop
{
    while ( myCount < 1000 )
    {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{


                             iconButton.alpha = 0.0;


                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             if (finished) {

                                 NSLog(@"animated");
                             }
                         }];


        [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{


                             iconButton.alpha = 1.0;


                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             if (finished) {

                                 NSLog(@"animated");
                             }
                         }];




        myCount++;
    }

}
```

this method is called from the viewdidload method,

pretty crude I know but its my best attempt, if you have any idea on how I could achieve this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about applying this in your button layer in `viewDidLoad`:

```
CABasicAnimation *pulseAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
pulseAnimation.duration = .5;
pulseAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.1];
pulseAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
pulseAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
pulseAnimation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX;
[YOURButton.layer addAnimation:pulseAnimation forKey:nil];
```

and you can experiment with it.

Comment: I had actually seen something similar to this code.. but i couldnt figure out how to apply it to a uibutton. I thought there would be something more than just mybutton.layer :P:P thanks for the heads up! animation is awesome! :P

Comment: hahaha, me too. I figured you just have to apply it in your button layer. so goodluck :)

Comment: This works really great however, when leaving the app and coming back, it stops animating. I made it, it's own method, and I call it in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear, but same thing.

Comment: Some reason... when i push a view controller onto the stack then add the uibutton it works... but when I present a view controller with the button, it doesn't animate..

Answer (score 5):

If you want it to repeat forever you could add the animation options to auto reverse and repeat, like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut | 
                            UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | 
                            UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^{
                     iconButton.alpha = 0.0;
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // You could do something here
                 }];
```

It will cause the alpha to first animate to 0.0, then back to the original (1.0) and then do those two things over and over and over...